# Unable to sort mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

## Note

I went through other answers before posting this, so expecting help here.

> **Mongoose model :**

```js
const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: { type: String, required: true },
  profile: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'Profile'
  },
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  image: { type: String },
  description: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 300, maxlength: 3000 },
  comments: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Comment'
  }],
  state: { type: Boolean, default: true },
  requests: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Request'
  }],
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }, // <== created at
```

> **Query:**

```js
const projects = await Project.find({
      state: true
    })
      .limit(10)
      .sort({ createdAt: -1 }) // <== have tried +1 and 
                               // also ({ date: -1 }), 
                               // it returns in ascending order
    return res.send(projects || [])
```

I have tried +1 in place of 1 and also ({ date: -1 }), it sends in ascending order.
I want the latest projects to be on top of array.

Comment: your query looks good, `{ createdAt: -1 }` this is correct one, you will get records in descending order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to resolve it.
I needed to sort before I put the limit.

```js
const projects = await Project.find({
      state: true
    })
      .sort({ createdAt: -1 })  // here 
      .limit(10)
    return res.send(projects || [])
```

Comment: Tried to reproduce this, but it works for me regardless of where I use `.limit()` - interesting.

Comment: @eol you are right, it does not matter when we use limit first and sort last or sort first and limit last.

Comment: What was the problem then? I'm confused :)